# Unable to style the year selector in showDatePicker() flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `showDatePicker()` to select the date in my flutter application. Everything works perfectly except that when I select the date, and try to change the year, everything else is just white, even if I select any year, it won't be displayed.

The code:

```
final datePicked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _dDate,
      firstDate: widget.firstDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: widget.lastDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      initialDatePickerMode: widget.initialDatePickerMode ?? DatePickerMode.day,
      initialEntryMode: widget.initialEntryMode ?? DatePickerEntryMode.calendar,
    );
```

The issue I am getting:

[image: date picker issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the `datePickerTheme` in `themeData`

```
datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData().copyWith(
      yearBackgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
      yearForegroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code :

```
DateTime? selectedDate;
TimeOfDay? selectedTime;

Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.black),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
     
    }
  }
```